# php convert mulitdimentional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Below is my output in array

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array (
                    [subjectId] => 13 
                    [subjectName] => Chemistry
                    [chapterId] => 1 
                    [chapterName] => Chem 1 
                ) 
    [1] => Array
                ( 
                    [subjectId] => 13 
                    [subjectName] => Chemistry 
                    [chapterId] => 2
                    [chapterName] => Chem 2 
                ) 

    [2] => Array ( 
                    [subjectId] => 14
                    [subjectName] => Mathematics 
                    [chapterId] => 5 
                    [chapterName] => Math 1 
                )
    [3] => Array ( 
                    [subjectId] => 14 
                    [subjectName] => Mathematics 
                    [chapterId] => 6 
                    [chapterName] => Math 2 
                )
)
```

what I am exactly looking for

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [subjectId] => 13
    [subjectName] =>  Chemistry
    [chapters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [chapterId] => 1
                                    [chapterName] => Chem 1
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [chapterId] => 2
                                    [chapterName] => Chem 2
                                )

                        )

)
[1] => Array
(
    [subjectId] => 14
    [subjectName] => Mathematics
    [chapters] => Array
                    (

                        [0] => Array
                            (

                                [chapterId] => 5
                                [chapterName] => Math 1

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (

                                [chapterId] => 6
                                [chapterName] => Math 2

                            )

                    )

    )

)
```

Comment: Welcome. To ask On Topic question, please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: Post what you have done so far.

Comment: foreach($get_subjects as $value)
   {
    $subjectIds[] = $value['subjectId'];
    
    if($subjectId != $value['subjectId'])
    {
     $subjectArray[] = array('subjectId'=>$value['subjectId'], 'subjectName'=>$value['subjectName'], 'chapters'=>$chaptersArray);
     
     $subjectId = $value['subjectId'];
    }
    
    $chaptersArray[] = array('subjectId'=>$value['subjectId'], 'chapterId'=>$value['chapterId'], 'chapterName'=>$value['chapterName'], 'chapterNo'=>$value['chapterNo']);
   }

Comment: Edit your code and not post it as a comment :) @Virendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `array_reduce` to group the array into an associative array and use `subjectId` as the key. Use `array_values` to convert the associative array into a simple array.

```
$result = array_reduce($arr, function($c, $v){
    if ( !isset( $c[$v['subjectId']] ) ) $c[$v['subjectId']] = array( 'subjectId'=> $v['subjectId'], 'subjectName' => $v['subjectName'], 'chapters' => array() );
    $c[$v['subjectId']]['chapters'][] = array( 'chapterId' => $v['chapterId'], 'chapterName' => $v['chapterName']);

    return $c;
}, array());

$result = array_values( $result );
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [subjectId] => 13
            [subjectName] => Chemistry
            [chapters] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [chapterId] => 1
                            [chapterName] => Chem 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [chapterId] => 2
                            [chapterName] => Chem 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [subjectId] => 14
            [subjectName] => Mathematics
            [chapters] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [chapterId] => 5
                            [chapterName] => Math 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [chapterId] => 6
                            [chapterName] => Math 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Eddie. You are awesome. Blessings from me